# Add new boostrap 4 card dynamicly

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I would know in js how to add dynamicly a new card. The code below allow to remove a card but not to add new.

I started something like that, but I am blocked.

The html code example

The card

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" aria-label="Insert" onClick="addAnother()" id="insert">
            <span aria-hidden="true">Insert</span>
        </button>
    </div>
     <div class="row"> 
        <ul class="row list-unstyled" id="list">
            <li class="col-md-4" id="element1">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Card title <a class="close" href="#">×</a></h4>
                        <p class="card-text">Some example text. Some example text.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                        <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="col-md-4" id="element2">
            <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Card title <a class="close" href="#">×</a></h4>
                        <p class="card-text">Some example text. Some example text.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                        <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="col-md-4" id="element1">                
            <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Card title <a class="close" href="#">×</a></h4>
                        <p class="card-text">Some example text. Some example text.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                        <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

the script>

Remove a card

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.close').click(function(){
    var $target = $(this).parents('li');
    $target.hide('slow', function(){ $target.remove(); });
    })

</script>
```

Add a card ==> this is element is not correct must be included the card code I think

```
<script>
    addAnother = function() {
        var ul = document.getElementById("list");
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        var children = ul.children.length + 1
        li.setAttribute("id", "element"+children)
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Element "+children));
        ul.appendChild(li)
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you mixing pure JS and jQuery? Which one do you want to use?

Comment: I am not good on that, js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could attach a click event using the id **#insert**, as you have with the close action, rather than referencing a function inline.

```
 $('#insert').click(function(){

     $( "ul#list" ).append( "<li>any html here</li>" );

});
```